# Running Backgroundworker from another Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 form. Form1 and Form2. Form1 gets the date interval from pop-up form2.

Form2 has search button. Search button do below;

```
 //form2
private void ubSAVE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form1 f1= new Form1();

f1.minDateCustomIO = Convert.ToDateTime(minDateString);
f1.maxDateCustomIO = Convert.ToDateTime(maxDateString);
f1.customIO = uosIO.CheckedIndex;

if (!f1.bgwCustomIO.IsBusy)
{
    f1.bgwCustomIO.RunWorkerAsync(); // run bgw on form1
}
}
```

That bgw on Form1 loads data to datatable etc. And all is works perfectly. Just one except;

Then i use RunWorkerCompleted event on that bgw like below;

```
//form1
public void bgwCustomIO_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ultraGrid1.DataSource = dtCustomIOM; // Here is the problem. 
    MessageBox.Show(dtCustomIOM.Rows.Count.ToString());
}
```

MessageBox verifies that i have rows in that datatable however I can't assign to the grid.

No errors, Nothing. Also i changed to their modifiers to public.

Just it doesn't assign it. What is the reason behind of this, and  how can i solve it ?

Comment: Your approach looks correct but where have you declared bgwCustomIO_RunWorkerCompleted event and what exact type of dtCustomIOM object.. There is nothing wrong assigning a datatable to ultrawingrid. See [Ref](http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBaseArticle.Aspx?ArticleID=1666)

Comment: @NiranjanKala I think the problem with the calling from another form/instance. Because if i do this without using another form. It works.

Comment: Am I right that you have `Form1` which you use to open `Form2` and then in `Form2` you have the code in your question?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, Form1 opens form2. And form2 trigger bgworker on form1

Comment: @johntrue - Your code in `Form2` is creating a brand new instance of `Form1` so you have two instances of `Form1` - you're probably updating the second `Form1` correctly, but the first instance is unchanged.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, I see now. However, how can i solve it ?

Comment: @johntrue - Pass a reference to `Form1` in to `Form2` when you create it. And then use the existing reference rather than creating a new one.

Comment: @Enigmativity My brain burned. Could you please write as an answer :)

Comment: @Enigmativity i am looking forward your reply. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `Form1` which you use to open `Form2` and then in `Form2` you create a brand new instance of `Form1` so you have two instances of `Form1` - you're updating the second `Form1` correctly, but the first instance is unchanged.

You just need to pass a reference to `Form1` in to `Form2` when you create it. And then use the existing reference rather than creating a new one.

Do something like this:

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 _form1;
    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        _form1 = form1;
    }
}
```